# JQuery getScript and get undefined variable

Tags: jquery

I have a fancybox that loads a script on close with

```
parent.$.getScript("js/reservation_special_reset.js")
```

and in the javascript file I have ..

```
            $('.time_start, .time_end').change(function() {
            var tid;

            tid = $(this).attr('id');
        });
```

However, FireBug always say tid is undefined. What is the problem here?

Comment: what's time_start and time_end, do they have "id" attr..?

Comment: Yes they do. I dont have any troubles getting the id on the parent page.